# responsive/viewport working in browsers but not in ios

Tags: ios, css, iphone, responsive-design, viewport

I think I'm losing my mind.

I have a site that the media queries and responsive behaviors are working just fine resizing in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, and is testing fine on my Android phone, but for some reason that I cannot figure out, it will not work on several iPhones and an iPad that I've tested on.

To answer your first question, my viewport is definitely there...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

...and I even tried putting in every CSS version I could to make sure that's not the issue.

```
@-wekbit-viewport{width:device-width;zoom:1;}
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width;zoom:1;}
@-o-viewport{width:device-width;zoom:1;}
@viewport{width:device-width;zoom:1;}
```

Still no dice.  I have validated my media queries and the code all looks good.  I am at a loss here.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on iOS devices, your site is injecting an extra viewport meta tag into the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">
```

That's what I saw on my iPhone6 simulator, and it is probably overriding your first viewport meta tag. I'm guessing you have a WordPress plugin that's trying to be too smart, and is injecting this extra tag only for iOS devices. I'd recommend your first step should be auditing your plugins, turning off anything that might be the culprit, and confirming the tag is gone by using the [free Xcode iOS simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [debugging with Safari](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a couple questions if you don't mind:
1) I'm looking in the Xcode iPhone simulator right now - how do I "debug with Safari?" I'm looking at the "Debug" menu and I don't see anything that can assist me.
2) Out of curiosity, what tool were you using that helped discover this extra viewport?

Comment: Follow the instructions in the last link in my answer. Basically, once 'Web Inspector' is turned on in your iPhone simulator (under 'Settings' > 'Advanced'), you can open Safari on your desktop and go to Develop > iPhone Simulator and inspect the website that you've loaded on the simulator. I didi that, and just looked through the source code until I discovered the meta tags were different on iOS.

Comment: Okay, I gotcha. I've never done it before so I didn't think to open Safari on my desktop to view something in a completely different program.  I'm new to Xcode.  Thank you for your help.